# Kept back upgrade of fwupd

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, partial-upgrade, fwupd

What's wrong now with fwupd? It was OK since May 1st, 2020 on newly installed Ubuntu 20.04

```
The following packages have been kept back:
   fwupd 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Happening to me too. If I try to force it, it wants to remove a bunch of important stuff :(

Comment: same happened to me, just run sudo apt-dist upgrade and then will be ok

Comment: @kannzzmm2 - Do yo think it is safe from the point of system integrity?

Comment: ITYM `sudo apt dist-upgrade` Tried it in a vm and it removed `fwupd-signed` and  `fwupdate-signed` After a reboot the vm didn't start the desktop. Not sure this is a winning strategy.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes exactly, I made a mistake.. When I updated my laptop with sudo apt dist-upgrade I think no package was removed, rebooted and it was working fine..
SergeySergeyev I think yes, because -- > dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a partial fix for a bug [LP #1883568](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fwupd/+bug/1883568)

Both packages, `fwupd` and `fwupd-signed` should be installed. One was uploaded, the other was [uploaded later](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fwupd/+bug/1883568/comments/1). So there was briefly a version mismatch, which prevented the new `fwupd` from installing.

There is Bug report on the mismatch: [LP #1883595](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fwupd-signed/+bug/1883595), and the `fwupd-signed` package has been uploaded to -proposed. Time to be patient.

Simply wait until fwupd-signed catches up, then both will install together automagically.

Do not try to force the newer version using dist-upgrade or full-upgrade. If you already did, then simply ensure that you have both packages installed.

Comment: What if you already did `dist-upgrade`? Does this need to be corrected somehow? And if so how?

Comment: The issue is gone with the recent update

Comment: @user000001 cleanup a mess by simply ensuring that both packages are installed.

Comment: @user000001 you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Thanks, I will if I face any issues, I re-installed `fwupd-signed` and the pc seems to work as expected, at least through `ssh`.

Comment: @user000001 glad to hear it. I had the same experience today.